# Cannot import a python module in a script outside the module

Tags: python, package, repository, importerror

I am working on a project structured in the following way:

```
repo-name/
   .venv
   src/
      __init__.py
      module1.py
      module2.py
   scratches/
      script1.py
   poetry.lock
   pyproject.toml
```

In script1.py I would like to use the classes defined in module1.py and module2.py, thus the file looks like:

```
#repo-name/scratches/script1.py

import src.module1 as m1
```

I am using Pycharm as IDE and I have marked src as source directory. If I run script1.py in Pycharm I do not get any error. However if I navigate into repo-name/scratches/ and run `poetry shell` and then run `python script1.py` I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

The absolute import cannot start from repo-name due to "-" in the name of the repository.

Is there any solution to run the script without changing the structure of the repository?

Comment: Did you  solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

You can do something like this:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Put this code at the top of your script, before the other imports.

### Explanation

with `sys.path.append()` you can add any folder/directory to the `sys.path` list. When you import stuff the interpreters looks for modules and packages in this list. So you can add your own src path to it and make the import work.

Moreover I used some `os` tools like `os.path.dirname` or `os.path.join` in combination with the `__file__` variable to automatically add the `./../` directory (where `src` is) and the `./` directory (where the script is).